# Citation of internet webpages that have limited lifetimes

Tags: internet, citation, footnotes

Some websites, especially news websites, either leave up content for limited periods, or archive content after a few days and charge readers to access their archives.  It seems to me that citations in a footnote or bibliography to the former are rather useless since the content cannot be accessed.  Should I just cite such material using the old-school methodology, as if it were printed matter available (maybe) on microfilm at the public library?  If archived and available only for a fee, should my footnote or bibliography also make reference to the charge?  How?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with English. Perhaps you could ask on the Academia site instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about English or the English language

Answer (score 2):

I just read a book that cited web sources.  It gave the web site link and date that the information was copied into his notes.  Presumably he has full copies of these pages in his own archives.  If not, sites like the Wayback Machine could presumably find it.

I don't know that you would have to cite a fee to access.  You don't have to cite if a book costs money to get access to from a library or collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the practice used by Wikipedia and note the date that it was "retrieved". That should be sufficient.

For example:

> Groer, Annie (June 2010). "[Chelsea Clinton's July 31 Wedding at Opulent Astor Courts"](http://www.politicsdaily.com/2010/07/02/chelsea-clintons-july-31-wedding-at-opulent-astor-courts-in-rhi/). Politics Daily. Retrieved August 5, 2010.